# Fan power for 3x3m wind tunnel?

Tags: aerodynamics, wind-tunnel

How much power do I need  for 3x3m wind tunnel,with airspeed up to 200km/h?
Some formula for calculation?

Comment: Is 3x3 m the cross sectional area of the inlet, or of the test cell?

Comment: While not an answer, the Wright Brothers Wind Tunnel is being upgraded, and is a similar size and speed to what you are asking about:  https://aeroastro.mit.edu/news/new-wright-brothers-wind-tunnel-will-be-largest-most-advanced-us-academic-tunnel so is a good point of reference.

Comment: https://www.aerospacetestinginternational.com/news/wind-tunnels/mits-wind-tunnel-gets-21st-century-update.html

Comment: @CamilleGoudeseune Test cell

Comment: IMO, this question could be reopened with a more clear correlation to aviation. Wind tunnels are used for many tests, only some of which are aviation-related. (i.e. automotive designers use wind tunnels to test and refine new designs for the automotive industry.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

200 km/h = 55,6 m/s
The density of air is taken as 1,23 kg/m3

You have a mass flow rate of 55,6 x 3 x 3 x 1,23 = 615 kg/s

In other words, in every second, you're moving a mass of air of 615 kg. The kinetic energy of that moving mass is 0,5 x 615 x 55,6^2 = 951 kilojoule. In a second, that's 951 kilowatt.

A lot of power, and that, assuming your fan has an efficiency of 100% and friction losses are zero...

Comment: This is true for an open windtunnel (where you have to continuously accelerate the air from 0 to 55.6 m/s), you can greatly reduce the required power with a [closed windtunnel](https://www.grc.nasa.gov/www/k-12/airplane/tuncret.html), where -after startup- you only need to compensate for the energy lost by the air as it travels along the path

Comment: @xxavier What is calculation for closed wind tunnel?

Comment: @xxavier, this calculation

Comment: @EBV821, a closed wind tunnel doesn't have a general formula, since the energy requirements are dominated by friction losses and other forms of inefficiency.